# Тестирование TTD

Tags: php, тестирование

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример автоматического тестирования TTD. Много раз слышал, но не видел и не до конца понимаю. Буду рад хорошим русскоязычным ссылкам на примеры. И что Вы думаете об этом: хорошо или плохо, когда применяется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть разные виды тестов, есть функциональные, есть модульные.
Функциональные предназначены для тестирования взаимодействий в системе, модульные - для изолированного тестирования отдельных частей программы.
Для последних в php есть класс `PHPUnit`. Он не очень сложный, наиболее интересная вещь в нем - это мок-объекты(заглушки для реальных объектов, с целью их изолирования).

Про phpunit читай здесь: [PHPUnit. Автоматические тесты](http://habrahabr.ru/post/87922/).

Про моки читай тут: [Использование моков в PHPUnit](http://smallcodenotes.blogspot.com/2011/07/phpunit.html).

PS: Для написания тестов с использованием моков, сам код должен быть под это приспособлен.